# Packages gone in Pycharm when using Kivy's python.bat as interpreter

Tags: pycharm, kivy

My python packages disappear once I configure the Project Interpreter correctly for Kivy. I'm using a fresh copy of the official package off of the Kivy-websites.

PyCharm uses quite a while to build skeletons when switching to the python.bat interpreter-file, and a Kivy 'Hello World' is working just fine. I'd rather not iterate through that too many times. The only thing missing now are the packages... Can anyone help me out? I'm using PyCharm 3.4.1.

I'd post a picture, but don't have the reputation. Thanks!

Edit: I should emphasize, they are not present in the Project Interpreter tab.

Comment: They aren't missing, you've just reconfigured pycharm to use kivy's python installation instead of the one you had before. Those modules aren't installed there.

Comment: There are a lot of modules in the Kivy-package which show up in the PyCharm-package list if I use the python.exe from the extracted Kivy-folder as the interpreter. They simply disappear once I select the .bat file instead, and as far as I understand it they really shouldn't.